# WPF: Dynamic ControlTemplate Generation

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, controltemplate

I am new to WPF and currently coding an editor for creating flow graph diagrams. These flow graphs consist of nodes and connections. The nodes are the objects for which i want to create a control template. One part of my node-items are the connectors. Different nodes can have a different number of connectors which should be specified in the member variables of a class the template is applied on.

My question is:
How can i set the number of connectors shown in the control template by a member variable of the parent object ?

Comment: What have you tried? It would help to get an answer if you posted some code samples instead of describing your problem vaguely.

Comment: Your question is misleading because of the use of `parent` object. I think you mean `DataContext` object. In that case your object needs a list of items (connectors) that will point them to other point, essentially we are talking about `LinkedList` here. Then you can have your `DataTempates` based on type. But we need to know what you are using and how. What I mean by that is a code sample.